# Is there any bug in Xcode's refactor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Today I want to change a name of a property,so I use refactor->rename to do this.The property is `UIButton * favorites` and I changed it to `UIButton * collectButton;`.After I finished rename I found some code interesting:

```
collectButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
favorites.frame = CGRectMake(165, 10, 145, 35);
favorites.tag = 1;
[btnBgImgView addSubview:collectButton];
```

I am very confused and I don't know why the Xcode just rename part of the property name I appointed.Is it a bug of Xcode?Have you ever meet this bug?I am afraid that I can't use the rename function anymore.

By the way,my Xcode version is 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I rename,there are some errors in my code,then I correct these errors everything goes well.So,before we refactor our code,make sure there is no error in our code,otherwise,maybe there would happen something strange to you.